# General purpose Table structure in Java (like ResultSet)

Tags: java, data-structures, resultset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Table like java data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691664/table-like-java-data-structure)

Does anyone know if there's a good general-purpose Table-based structure that I can use for manipulating data?  ResultSet is an interface, so am I stuck having to fully implement something if I want similar functionality without a database?  Apache Commons Collections does not seem to have anything immediately suitable.

Comment: what operations do you need your table to have?  What are you going to do with it?  If you don't need anything fancey the beans aproach by BalusC seems right for you.

Comment: having named column headers for sure at a minimum.  perhaps even join logic.  There's a large amount of stuff I do in my day job that's amenable to table-oriented processing, but it would be overkill to load it into a database and run operations on it.  Currently I've been wrapping some logic around some List< Map<String, Object> >

Answer (score 6):

*Usually* you use a [`List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or [`Set`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of Javabeans for this. Each Javabean in turn represents one real world entity, like a row in a database. For example an `User`:

```
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    // Add/generate getters+setters.
}
```

with

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
users.add(new User(1L, "foo", 30));
users.add(new User(2L, "bar", 20));
//...
```

The `List` provides methods for fast access by index.

For an undetermined amount of properties (columns) you may consider to use a [`Map<String, Object>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead where the key represents the property (column) name.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> table = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
row.put("id", 1L);
row.put("name", "foo");
row.put("age", 30);
table.add(row);
// ...
```

It only adds a bit more overhead than a simple Javabean since those string keys needs to be stored in the heap as well.

If you don't care about column names, then you can also just go ahead with a `List<List<Object>>` or maybe even a less flexible `Object[][]`. With both you can easily access elements by `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an **In-Memory Database**, such as HSQLDB or H2. They are *very* lightweight and fast, provide the JDBC interface you seem to want and also provide the JOIN functionality you mention.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) libraries offer several general purpose [Table](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) implementations - HashBasedTable, [TreeBasedTable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeBasedTable.html). The classes are generic so any class can act as a row/column key.

Example from the docs:

```
Table<Vertex, Vertex, Double> weightedGraph = HashBasedTable.create();
weightedGraph.put(v1, v2, 4.0);
weightedGraph.put(v1, v3, 20.0);
weightedGraph.put(v2, v3, 5.0);

weightedGraph.row(v1); // returns a Map mapping v2 to 4, v3 to 20
weightedGraph.column(v3); // returns a Map mapping v1 to 20, v2 to 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the `DefaultTableModel` will meet your requirements. It is generally used with a JTable to display data but it can be used stand alone.

Or the [`BeanTableModel`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/) based on the `RowTableModel` has a few more dynamic features that allows you to access rows of data easier.

Answer (score 0):

Java 6 has a `CachedRowSet` interface and comes with a Sun class, `CachedRowSetImpl`. This probably is the closest thing stock out of the box to what you're looking for. It's designed to be populated by a `ResultSet`.

If that suits you it's probably exactly what you're looking for.

If not, you may have issues populating it properly.