# What is an efficient row-column (ResultSet like) data structure for Java?

Tags: java, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Table like java data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691664/table-like-java-data-structure)

I am looking for a Table-like data structure for Java. So far I have not been able to find one and it is really frustrating as I know for sure there must be one. Please note this has nothing to do with a graphical representation of the table, just the logical model.

The idea is simple, you have a table like:

```
+-------+-----+-----------+
| Name  | Age | city      |
+-------+-----+-----------+
| Steve | 21  | London    |
| John  | 40  | Amsterdam | 
+-------+-----+-----------+
```

Now I need to iterate over the different rows and retrieve the values based on the column name. It has to be flexible so I don't know the column names up front (so a list of beans is not an option). The best structure I could find that has this ability is a *java.sql.ResultSet*, but I don't feel comfortable using that in a non SQL related context. I also don't want a list of HashMaps as that would mean storing the keys for every row, which would be very inefficient.

It seems like such a basic structure yet I cannot find anything about it due to the overwhelming amount of GUI related posts when searching for table like structures in Java.

**EDIT**

For a concrete example of what I need, the following piece of code:

```
TableStructure table = getTable(); // Gets my desired table with its filling

while (table.next()){
    System.out.println("Name: " +  table.get("Name"));
    System.out.println("Age: " + table.get("Age"));
    System.out.println("City: " + table.get("City"));
    System.out.println("NonExistent: " + table.get("NonExistent"));
}
```

Should produce the following output:

```
Name: Steve
Age: 21
City: London
NonExistent: null
Name: John
Age: 40
City: Amsterdam
NonExistent: null
```

Comment: What about this? { Object get(int row, int column); } Give a look at javax.swing.table.TableModel subclasses.

Comment: Two dimensional arrays, HashMaps, there are lots of datastructures which can model tables so it is not suprising that there is no such specific thing in the Java API.

Comment: Think about `List<T>` or `List<HashMap>`

Comment: @Mark that post proposes a structure for sorting, not iterating over the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ResultSet` is a list (or a set, dependant on necessity of ordering and multiplicity of elements) of tuples, so a *really* generic answer would be

```
class TableStructure<Tuple>
{
    List<Tuple> tuples;
    Iterator iterator;

    public Tuple next() 
    {
        if ( iterator == null ) { iterator = tuples.iterator(); /* NPE prone */ }
        return iterator.next()
    }
}
```

(or better, have `TableStructure` extend  `List` and use the iterator directly)

where

```
class Tuple { Map<String,Object> attributes; }
```

This construct allows for different row sizes within your table, which in a DB setting violates the first (or the second?) normal form principle.

Hope that helps a bit.

Cheers,

Comment: Extra thanks to the actual example code!

Comment: wouldn't Map<string,object> cause boxing/unboxing? this may cause issues for large enough datasets

Answer (score 0):

What about a `List<Map<String, ?>>`? For a concrete implementation, you could use `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>`.