# Data Structure to store given data, search and remove operation should be efficient

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am working on a project in **Java**.

In that project, I first get URL from web using **jsoup**.

Now for performance reason, I have to store

```
[ tag name, tag Id, tag Class name ]
```

in a container, and it is known that tag id is either NULL or unique.

Example,

```
["a", "fullSiteLink", ""]
["div", "", "mob-footer"]
["div", "", "clear"]
["br", "", ""]
["ul", "", "mob-footer-links"]
```

So please tell me any data structure that stores these information for every tag, and we can search, remove any tag in efficient way.

Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell us what the greater goal is? Why you need O(1) removal time? How big is the DOM you're processing?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum DOM is of any online shoping website item. I need this to improve my algorithm efficiency. My questions link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718235/optimized-algorithm-to-compare-templates-of-two-urls

Comment: I think you need to re-think your algorithm from that question to begin with. I do the same thing in O(n) and it makes website templates act like a metric space, I use an approximation algorithm to filter to sort the URLs initially into templates and then iterate them more to create equiv. relation. You don't need to remove elements, you need to keep score based on stylesheets, attributes, classes, ids, placement of tags, scripts, navigation link placement etc. pages might not have many classes and IDs but may still be identical. I would love to help you more but I can't (contact obligation)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Can we chat on this problem, to clear some of my doubts. So that I can also write my code efficiently.

Comment: Sure, open a chat room and invite me. Just remember, there is only so much I can help you with.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Please tell me any DataStructure of above question.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum PLease explain your above said lines "You don't need to remove elements, you need to keep score based on stylesheets, attributes, classes, ids, placement of tags, scripts, navigation link placement etc. pages might not have many classes and IDs but may still be identical"

Comment: We've had an hour of discussion out of my own free time where I explained to you what strategies there are in order to do this. I can't give you code. Good luck.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum  Ohk. Yes, you explained me yesterday, thanks for that. But that  goes bounce to me. I seriously didn't get the concept of keep maintaining scores instead of removing elements. Why you did that ? How you did that ? These are the simple question and if you have time please explain this, step by step, or tell me your algorithm step by step. I will implement that.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Please tell me one thing, how can you handle dynamic content of any page. As it is not retrieved by Jsoup parser in Java. In which language you wrote your code? By which tool you get the dynamic content ?

Answer (score 1):

> So please tell me any data structure that stores these information for
>   every tag, and we can search, remove any tag in efficient way.

I would use a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).  It is one of the most efficient data structures for quick insertion, lookup, and removal.

If that isn't suited to your intend search style, [a binary tree](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~weiss/dsj3/code/BinaryTree.java) is flexible data structure for O(log n) search, insertion, and removal.

Comment: If there is any data structure that  stores duplicates, then that is the best for my case. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691664/table-like-java-data-structure/10074077#  But this has one problem, it does not takes duplicate row. So help in that, please

Comment: The usual solution to storing duplicates is to have a HashMap that maps keys to a list (or linked link) of values that share the same key.