# Which data structure for calendar of a month

Tags: java

I have code from a text book to print the month of a calendar. It prints a blank for all days before 1st day of month, but not after last day of month. Although the code works correctly, the problem is that it is hard to test it with automation and make any updates without breaking it.

I want to make this code easily testable. I want to move the calendar month into a table like data structure and the printing logic into a separate method. That is, separate the data and formatting.

Which data structure/DS can I use to represent a table, besides a 2d array or a custom class ? I prefer a DS which is already included in Java, or is from a popular and well maintained library. Ideally, the DS should allow me to (1) get the day on which a date occurs (directly, and not by sequential iteration) and (2) get any row and iterate it.

I could not get an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691664/table-like-java-data-structure). I prefer to not create my own DS with utility methods, unless there is no alternative. Please advise.

```
 Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
                           1
   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
  16  17  18  19  20  21  22
  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
  30  31
```

The code :

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;

//TODO : Add tests.
public class Calendar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printCalendar(3, 2020);
    }

    public static void printCalendar(int month, int year) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1);

        System.out.println(" Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun");
        DayOfWeek weekday = date.getDayOfWeek();
        int value = weekday.getValue(); // 1 = Monday, ... 7 = Sunday

        for (int i = 1; i < value; i++) {
            System.out.print("    ");
        }

        while (date.getMonthValue() == month) {
            System.out.printf("%4d", date.getDayOfMonth());
            date = date.plusDays(1);
            if (date.getDayOfWeek().getValue() == 1) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        if (date.getDayOfWeek().getValue() != 1) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    //TESTS (for now)
    /*
        1 - Calendar should have exactly 7 columns.
        2 - Header/top row should always be from Mon to Sun.
        3 - 1st & last days of month should be in correct place.
        4 - All days before 1st day of month should be empty.
    */

}
```

Comment: What about a 31 element array?

Comment: This is so specific, it almost certainly does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO forget using `java.time` classes for rendering.

Try something like this:

Have a `Day` class:

```
class Day {
    int number;
    String render() {
        return number == 0 ? "    " : String.format("%4d", number);
    }
}
```

and a `Week` class:

```
class Week {
    List<Day> days;
    String render() {
        return days.stream().map(Day::render).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
    }
}
```

and a `Month` class:

```
class Month {
    List<Week> weeks;
    String render() {
        return weeks.stream().map(Day::render).collect(
            Collectors.joining("\n", " Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun", "\n")
        );
    }
}
```

for "blank" days, don't give assign a number. Build up your days into weeks, your weeks into month, then:

```
System.out.println(month.render());
```